# Strange "fuzz" When Rendering Texture on Plane in XNA 4.0

Tags: xna

I'm just getting started with XNA and I am sure I am missing something very simple.  I have a quad plane I drew for the ground.  On this plane I wrapped a 2D texture.  The texture looks good up close, but as I move the camera around, I see a bunch of white artifacts all over the place. They disappear as I get close to them.  I'm guessing this is a sampling problem or something similar, but I am stuck.

First, I created a QuadDrawer class to draw the plane for me.  It's derived from DrawableGameComponent.

QuadDrawer:

```
class QuadDrawer : DrawableGameComponent
  {
    private string _textureName;
    private Texture2D _texture;
    private BasicEffect _effect;

    private float _size = 100;

    private VertexPositionNormalTexture[] _vertices;
    private int[] _indices;

    public QuadDrawer(Game game, float size, string textureName)
      : base(game)
    {
      this._size = size;
      this._textureName = textureName;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
      BuildVertices();
      base.Initialize();
    }

    private void BuildVertices()
    {
      _vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[4];
      _indices = new int[6];

      _vertices[0].Position = Vector3.Forward + Vector3.Left;
      _vertices[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f);
      _vertices[1].Position = Vector3.Backward + Vector3.Left;
      _vertices[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
      _vertices[2].Position = Vector3.Forward + Vector3.Right;
      _vertices[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);
      _vertices[3].Position = Vector3.Backward + Vector3.Right;
      _vertices[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);

      for (int i = 0; i < _vertices.Length; i++)
      {
        _vertices[i].Normal = Vector3.Up;
        _vertices[i].Position *= _size;
        _vertices[i].TextureCoordinate *= _size;
      }

      _indices[5] = 0; _indices[4] = 1; _indices[3] = 2;
      _indices[2] = 2; _indices[1] = 1; _indices[0] = 3;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
      _texture = this.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(_textureName);
      _effect = new BasicEffect(this.GraphicsDevice);
      _effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
      _effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
      _effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

      _effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
      _effect.TextureEnabled = true;
      _effect.Texture = _texture;

      base.LoadContent();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
      MyGame game = this.Game as MyGame;

      GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.AnisotropicWrap;
      GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

      _effect.View = game.Camera.ViewMatrix;
      _effect.Projection = game.Camera.ProjectionMatrix;

      foreach (EffectPass pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
      {
        pass.Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, _vertices, 0, 4, _indices, 0, 2);
      }
      base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

  }
```

From my main Game class's Initialize() method, I simply instantiate this object and pass in the GameObject, Size and the Texture name I want to use:

```
_floor = new QuadDrawer(this, 100.0f, "Textures/checker");
  this.Components.Add(_floor);
```

Once the object is added to my Components collection, the Draw method of my QuadDrawer gets called and all should be good.  Here is an image of what I am seeing.  Note this should be solid gray with light color lines running in a grid pattern.  The white artifacts appear to move as you move the camera around the surface, but disappear when you get close.

Here is picture showing the white artifacts:

[image: Fuzzy]

This is a close up showing how it should look:
[image: Close Up]

Here is another picture showing how bad it can get from a distance:
[image: Better view of the problem]

And here is what it should look like from a distance:
[image]

The picture is not the best, but you can see what I am talking about.  When the camera moves, it gets really bad.  I've seen this texture used in other places and it works fine.  Any idea what it could be?

I'd be happy to provide more info if you need it.

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Although the artifacts might be obvious to you, I am still having trouble seeing the problem you are describing. Are you able to get a better example image and maybe circle an instance of said artifact(s)? Thanks.

Comment: I added another image that shows it much better.  All the white lines are what should not be there.  In the new image, you can see how the white grid lines start to swirl when they get further from the camera.  I will upload another picture with what I am expecting it to look like.  By the way, this is happening with any texture I apply, not just this one.  Thanks!

Comment: @Layoric - I added another image at the very bottom showing what the scene should look like from a distance.  Any help is much appriciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to **enable mipmaps for your texture**. If it's just a stand-alone asset, you can select it in Solution Explorer, press F4 to get to properties, expand the "Content Processor" node and set "Generate Mipmaps" to true.

[This article by Shawn Hargreaves explains why](https://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html). Look at the difference between these two pictures from that article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-70-20-metablogapi/2388.image_5F00_401AFB8B.png

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-70-20-metablogapi/6518.image_5F00_1B896E07.png

(Looks a lot like your example images, doesn't it?)

Then, if you're going to be viewing at such oblique angles, you need to **enable anisotropic filtering** (Layoric explained how in his answer). This image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering) illustrates what anisotropic filtering is for - note how it horizontally "un-blurs" the background (which was caused by the mipmaps).

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c0/Anisotropic_compare.png))</sub>

Comment: This resolved my issue completely.  Clearly I still have a lot to learn.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an anistropic filtering problem. I notice you do have `GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.AnisotropicWrap;` being used. I would suggest having a look at Shawn Hargreaves [article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/09/24/texture-filtering-anisotropy.aspx) and specifically the following lines.

```
device.SamplerStates[0].MinFilter = TextureFilter.Anisotropic;
device.SamplerStates[0].MagFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
device.SamplerStates[0].MipFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
device.SamplerStates[0].MaxAnisotropy = <n>;
```

Also,

Make sure the code is being set at the right time as a `Effect.Begin` will reset these filter settings. Another code snippet to help.

```
// inside draw perform any other required draw code  

// Call begin on the basic effect and on the pass to initialize BasicEffect's render settings  
basicEffect.Begin();  
basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Begin();  

// Set your desired filter settings  
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MinFilter = TextureFilter.Anisotropic;  
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MagFilter = TextureFilter.Anisotropic;  
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MipFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;  
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MaxAnisotropy = 16;  

// Commit the changes to basic effect so it knows you made modifications  
basicEffect.CommitChanges();  

// Now perform you rendering to see Anisotropic filtering in effect
```

code snippet thanks to [Jeromy Wash](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/12956/12956.aspx) over at [AppHub forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/), another great place to get help from the masters of XNA :)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I read through the blog post and applied different types of filters - non of which solved my problem.  Even when removing the AnisotropicWrap sampler, I still get the artifacts.  I just don't know enough about this stuff yet to hunt this one down...

Comment: Updated with some more suggestions @Scott

Comment: I believe 4.0 did away with BasicEffect.Begin() and BasicEffect.CommitChanges().  However, I did apply the filters you suggested above (using the 4.0 syntax) and I still have the same issue.  I am going to pull out all my code from the QuadDrawer class and addit directly to my Game class to see if it could be an issue with that class.  Thanks for the help.  If you have more suggestions....  I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Did assign the filters within your effects loop?

Answer (score 1):

Anisotropic filtering will not help. You best solutions (although not cheap) would be to use either [Supersampling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/26/supersampling.aspx), which will definitelly solve your issue, but is quite expensive, or [Multisampling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/27/multisampling.aspx), which will solve your issue depending on the squares geometry that you are using.

In my personal experience, multisampling is something that you can generally leave on in any case, since modern graphics cards, do have the capability to render it with not a lot of cost to you, unless you are building a very GPU heavy application\game. Also Supersampling is not totally out of the question, even though it is quite expensive to use, for the same reason as above, but test to see that you will not have a great performance penalty.

Comment: While anisotropic filtering *alone* will not help (although it will help if used correctly), supersampling will only *reduce* the problem not solve it. Multisampling would only help if this were geometry - the OP is using a texture (and again it would only reduce the problem). See the article linked in my answer for a deeper explanation of why these two solutions won't work.